# Understanding Maya Matrix File - Converting to OpenGL ES iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, 3d, maya

I am working on parsing a Maya dae file onto OpenGL ES on the iPhone.

I am able to get all the objects to successfully render on iPhone, however with one problem - the objects are all over the place and not aligned to one another in the scene.

I understand that this is because Maya uses matrixes to describe where each object should be in the scene. In the dae file they look like this :

```
<node id="objects01-node" name="object01">
            <matrix>1 0 0 9983.33 0 0 -1 -8850.6 0 1 0 135036 0 0 0 1</matrix>
            <instance_geometry url="#object01-mesh">
```

My question is does anyone know how I can translate this matrix data and then apply it to the models in my scene ?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you've got the matrix:

```
1  0  0  9983.33
0  0 -1 -8850.6
0  1  0  135036
0  0  0  1
```

The translation is always

> (m[12]/m[15], m[13]/m[15], m[14]/m[15])

(where m is your matrix).
So it is (9983.33, -8850.6, 135036) in this particular case.
Rotation matrix is

```
1  0  0
0  0 -1
0  1  0
```

Read this [article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Scaling).

You can fetch all these values, or can store the whole matrix and then just use glMultMatrix before rendering an object.

Comment: Hi Max - what does m[12]/m[15] mean ? Is it position. 12 in the matrix divided by position 15 ?

Comment: m[15] is not position. It is augmented value (usually named w). We need it to be able to combine (multiply) rotation and translation matrices. You should read abound homogeneous coordinates. W is usually 1.

Comment: Thank you - I'm glad Max exists.